# Excel CopyMemory 4 bytes to Integer

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to copy four bytes into an integer variable. In short, I wants to perform UNION in vba.
My function:

```
Private Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" ( _
    ByRef Destination As Any, _
    ByRef Source As Any, _
    ByVal Length As Long)
```

and

```
Function Byte2Int32(ByVal Num1 As Byte, ByVal Num2 As Byte, ByVal Num3 As Byte, ByVal Num4 As Byte) As Integer
  Dim D As Integer
  Dim TabData(3) As Long
  
  TabData(0) = Num4
  TabData(1) = Num3
  TabData(2) = Num2
  TabData(3) = Num1
  
  CopyMemory D, TabData(0), 4
  Byte2Int32 = D
  
End Function
```

Function call: `=Byte2Int32(C6;D6;E6;F6)` where C6 = 40, D6 = 20, E6 = 50, F6 = 68.
Results: 68. What should I change so that I can copy the memory? Ultimately, the function is supposed to work for the variable double ?. For two bytes, it works.

Answer (score 2):

Some types on your function are incorrect.
This version seems to be working:

```
Private Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" ( _
    ByRef Destination As Any, _
    ByRef Source As Any, _
    ByVal Length As Long)

Function Byte2Int32(ByVal Num1 As Byte, ByVal Num2 As Byte, ByVal Num3 As Byte, ByVal Num4 As Byte) As Long
  Dim D As Long
  Dim TabData(3) As Byte
  
  TabData(0) = Num4
  TabData(1) = Num3
  TabData(2) = Num2
  TabData(3) = Num1
  
  CopyMemory D, TabData(0), 4
  Byte2Int32 = D
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you, it works much better now!